# Pass reference to function that takes `std::unique_ptr`

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a reference to my object of type `MyType`, but I need to call a function, say `myFunction` that takes a `std::unique_ptr<MyType>`. What is the correct way to call `myFunction`? My attempt below seems to cause an "invalid pointer" error:

```
#include <memory>

class MyType {};
MyType myGlobalObj;

MyType& myGetter () {
    return myGlobalObj;
}

void myFunction (std::unique_ptr<MyType> ptr) {
    // Do important stuff
}

int main () {
    MyType& myObj = myGetter();
    std::unique_ptr<MyType> myPtr;
    myPtr.reset(&myObj);
    myFunction(std::move(myPtr)); // This causes "invalid pointer" at run time.
    myPtr.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `myPtr.reset(&myObj);` - don't do that. unique pointers and shared pointers are for managing *dynamic* ownership. `myGlobalObject` cannot be used in a unique-ptr paradigm. There is no way to 'fake' a unique-ptr hosting that thing, much less deliver said-same to a by-value parameter expecting to take (and ultimately release) ownership of it.

Comment: `myFunction` signature is saying "You need to give me a `unique_ptr<MyType>` that I can become the owner of, and you're not getting it back because I'm going to consume it."  You can call the function this way:  `myFunction(std::make_unique<MyType>(myGetter()));` which will make a copy of the object wrapped that into a unique_ptr smart pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible without either doing a (deep-)copy of `myGlobalObj` or modifying `myFunction`.

A `std::unique_ptr` takes ownership of the memory that is used to store the contained object. That means that the `std::unique_ptr` may free (or reallocate, or whatever) the memory that it 'owns'. What it would do in your case: As soon as the `ptr` variable goes out of scope at the end of `myFunction`, it will attempt to free the memory that it points to. Since `myGlobalObj` is a global variable, its memory may never be freed (before a controlled shutdown of your program…)

Thus, you should not ever wrestle a global object into a `std::unique_ptr` (or a `std::shared_ptr`, for that matter). If there is really no way of refactoring that method to take anything else than a `std::unique_ptr`, you must make a copy (on the heap!) of `myGlobalObj`, wrap that into a `std::unique_ptr`, and pass it to `myFunction`. Keep in mind that this way, `myFunction` loses the ability to modify `myGlobalObj`.